# Google Map API v3 Geocoding: should I use full address or just part of it?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

When geocoding human readable address into lat lng e.g. 3 mystreetname, myarea, mycity, mypostcode.

Should I use full address or just some part of it, for instance post code?

I know that it works ether way, but I'd like to know what would be the best practice to avoid errors geocoding locations.

Comment: The more information you give the geocoder the better the answer it will give you (if you give it inconsistent information, however, it might not return any results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some cities span multiple postal codes, and some postal codes span multiple cities. You might not have problems with smaller data sets but as you start dealing with a lot of addresses things like that can pop up. It's entirely possible that there are two 201 Main Streets in the same zip code, located in two different cities.

So yep, give as much detail as you can.

I'd really recommend storing your information in a spatial datatype if your database supports that as well.

Comment: I've actually got to disagree, I just did a test of possible alternatives, and I've found that more information can be better, but descriptive words are actually worse. Works such as 'restaurant' or 'food' or 'indian' all make geocoding worse.

Comment: I guess I'd say that you want to provide as much street-address information as possible, but the name of the business and the type of industry are just going to muck up the works.

Answer (score 1):

This link is the google's documentation of geocoding
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1

And refer below link for the real time sample..!
http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html

And for better results use more information so that you will get accurate answers

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I would try running the queries with as much detail as possible, and if a query fails rerun without the zip, as sometimes the zip causes problems with the google api (especially zips greater then 5 digits).